# Many MySQL databases - problem?

Tags: mysql, database

I'd like to know if it is any kind of issue having 200+ MySQL databases on the same server. None of them are probably going to be very used, I'm just wondering if there is any issue having so much databases.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. Shared-hosting services will usually have many hundreds of databases on each server, all relatively small. Just be sure you're not confusing "Databases" with "Tables," as is a problem for those new to that area of development.

Comment: This question I made about multiple databases is related to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924872/prefixing-mysql-tables-or-many-mysql-databases
It seems like having multiple databases instead of using a parser and prefixing tables is much more faster and easier to maintain, so I've decided going with the multiple database scenario.

Answer (score 1):

No issues, they are just taking some disk space. If you don't need them, you can delete them or take backup of them then delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple tables is the problem, not databases.

Having enough tables will result in very poor performance as they'll need to be closed and reopened. With some engines (MyISAM) this also blows away some of the cache, which makes for very poor performance.

Whether you put them in multiple databases or a single one, makes no difference from a performance point of view.

It does however, make permissions management much easier.